# Unexpected CSS Behavior?

Tags: html, css

While playing around with divider lines that take the full height of a container without a parents height, I stumbled across the below scenario. Can any one figure out why setting the dividers to `position:absolute` and `display:inline-block` does not cause them to float all the way to left of the parent container like expected? Why are they actually inline?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.divider{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emb58a4v/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because both `left` and `right` are `auto`.

Then, according to [§10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width),

> [If] 'left' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'width' is not 'auto', then if the
>   'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position]
>   containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the [static position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#static-position), otherwise
>   set 'right' to the [static-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#static-position). Then solve for 'left' (if
>   'direction is 'rtl') or 'right' (if 'direction' is 'ltr').

Where the static position is defined as

> The static position for 'left' is the distance from the left edge of
>   the containing block to the left margin edge of a hypothetical box
>   that would have been the first box of the element if its 'position'
>   property had been 'static' and 'float' had been 'none'.

If you don't want that, specify a value:

```css
.divider {
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can any one figure out why setting the dividers to `position:absolute` and `display:inline-block` does not cause them to float all the way to left of the parent container like expected?

Because you did not specify a `left` value, so it is implicitly `auto`, and that means their left edge is positioned at the place they would have in normal flow, if they were not absolutely positioned.

This behavior is described and specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#static-position

---

<del>And btw., setting `display: inline-block` has no effect here, the calculated value of `display` will be `block` automatically, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo</del>

`display: inline-block` is necessary here to make the elements take their *static position* in between the boxes in the first place – so it *is* necessary for the observed effect to work. (Only “after” `position:absolute` is applied, the *computed value* will *become* `block`.)

---

And the technique you have chosen to position those dividers here might not be the best choice, at least if your layout is fluid – narrow the result window of your fiddle to a point where the three red boxes don’t all fit onto one line, and you’ll see what I mean …

Comment: its not a technique i have chosen, and i dont plan on using it, like i said i just stumbled across it and found it interesting. Also, remove `display: inline-block` and the dividers float to the left. but anyways, +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you want all dividers to stay on the left of their parent, change their display style

instead of:

```
display: inline-block;
```

use:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: thats not what i was looking for, and im not looking for a solution, just an explanation